# How to find elements on div container using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am testing a website which has div containers one is like lightbox dialogbox containing subscription detail and other is at footer which behave like frame and unscrollable also contains subscription details.

How would I switch to these div tags and find elements on it.

I have tried this

```
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("sign-up-container")));
  List<WebElement> subButtons = driver.findElements(By.className("btn-black"));
 for(WebElement btn: subButtons){
        System.out.println(btn.getText());
    }
```

and similarly for other div conatiner and its gives me error "Element is not a frame element". That  error is right. 
Also if I comment the first line then I received empty string.
How can I find the elements on these div tags? Please let me know if you need more detail.
HTML for subscription button on both div is same.

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-black" value="Sign Up">
```

and

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-black" value="subscribe">
```

Comment: So, are you trying to click on those `div`(s) which pops up lightbox and you want to interact with elements on that lighbox?

Comment: You should use xpath to locate elements .  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361535/webdriver-findelements-by-xpath