# Finding element with dynamic xpath not working

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver

I have this in the HTML:

```
<textarea name="comment" class="form-control" rows="3" id="textarea_1160688690910416779_2159935466"></textarea>
```

I want to interact with id=textarea_, but the numbers are constantly changing after the "_". To solve this, I used this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("[starts-with(@id, 'textarea')")).sendKeys(comment);
```

However I am getting the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:
```

Comment: First of all, the XPath expression posted is not valid : `//*[starts-with(@id, 'textarea_')]`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[starts-with(@id,'textarea_')]")).sendKeys(comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is that you need to add '//' before your current XPath.
You could either use starts-with, this way:

```
("//textarea[starts-with(@id, 'textarea_')]")
```

You could also give 'contains' a try:

```
("//textarea[contains(@id, 'textarea_')]")
```

In both ways, you could use //*[... instead of textarea, for more cases

Answer (score 0):

**Your Xpath is not a valid Xpath.**

- It should contain a path and tag name
- and it should be balanced (your [ is not closed)

So, if your tag is, textarea, and if it is at top: use **/textarea**

if not at top, use **//textarea**

This gives: **"//textarea[starts-with(@id, 'textarea')]"**

To use with selenium, you could also read that: [JAVA - How to use xpath in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566437/java-how-to-use-xpath-in-selenium)

and that: [Webdriver findElements By xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16361535/webdriver-findelements-by-xpath)